# C# Monotouch/Xamarin - TextView Hyperlinks

Tags: c#, hyperlink, xamarin.ios, textview, xamarin

1. Is it possible to have a paragraph of text within a textview, where some of the text itself can be a hyperlink?
2. i.e. Touching a particular word would allow the triggering of some action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a `UIWebView` for full flexibility of layout and style, or you can use `UITextView` and set `u.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link;` in order to activate links in your text view.

Comment: Thanks. Do either one of those options allow me to pass in a full paragraph of text, but only set hyperlinks on explicit words? e.g. The quick brown [FOX] jumps over the lazy [DOG] - Where only the words "fox" and "dog" are hyperlinks, but my code looks something like SomeObject.Text = "The quick brown [FOX] jumps over the lazy [DOG]"; ?

Comment: I don't understand. Of course you can have links on single words, your text would have to be `"Hello <a href=\"http://google.com\">World</a>!"`. In a UIWebView you can manually react on the link clicks via a delegate. With UITextView you will have to override OpenUrl in UIApplication.